# Django Admin site 'int' has no len() error on model form submit

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-admin

When trying to submit a model form (/add/) in the Django admin site, I get the following error:

`TypeError object of type 'int' has no len()`

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/app/card/add/

Django Version: 3.1.4
Python Version: 3.8.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'app',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django_filters',
 'markdownify',
 'ckeditor',
 'ckeditor_uploader',
 'rest_framework',
 'smart_selects',
 'storages',
 'widget_tweaks']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 614, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 233, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1653, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1534, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1582, in _changeform_view
    change_message = self.construct_change_message(request, form, formsets, add)
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1055, in construct_change_message
    return construct_change_message(form, formsets, add)
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 503, in construct_change_message
    changed_data = form.changed_data
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 449, in changed_data
    if field.has_changed(initial_value, data_value):
  File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 1385, in has_changed
    if len(initial) != len(data):

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/app/card/add/
Exception Value: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Models.py:

```py
class Card(models.Model):
    visible = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Visible to Customers?")
    software = models.ForeignKey(Software, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = ChainedForeignKey(
        Product,
        chained_field="software", 
        chained_model_field="software",
        auto_choose=True,
        show_all=False,
        sort=True,
        default=0,)

    utility = models.ForeignKey(Utility, verbose_name='Utilities', default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    function = ChainedForeignKey(
        Function,
        chained_field="utility", 
        chained_model_field="utility",
        auto_choose=True,
        show_all=False,
        sort=True,
        default=0,)
   
    error_code = models.ForeignKey(ErrorCode, default=0, on_delete=models.CASCADE, help_text="Please only use for error codes, if no code, leave empty.")
    message = RichTextUploadingField(default="", help_text='Message can include markdown for styling.')
    tags = RichTextUploadingField(default="", blank=True, null=False, help_text='Add Text that can be used as tags for searching for this card.')
    encountered = models.ManyToManyField(Encountered, default=0, verbose_name='Encountered in', help_text='Version or Year. Select "N/A" if unknown.')
    resolved = models.ForeignKey(Resolved, default=0, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Resolved in', help_text='If not resolved, enter "N/A".')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    card_created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        related_name='card_created_by',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Created by',
        null=True)
    last_edited_by = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        related_name='last_edited_by',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Last edited by',
        null=True)
    card_view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Solution(models.Model):
    card = models.ForeignKey(Card, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    cause = RichTextUploadingField(blank=False, help_text='Message can include markdown for styling.')
    cause_solution = RichTextUploadingField(blank=False, verbose_name='Solution', help_text='Message can include markdown for styling.')
    solution_edited_by = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        related_name='solution_edited_by',
        verbose_name='Last edited by',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Admin.py:

```py
class SolutionsInlineFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.solution_edited_by = request.user
        obj.save()

    def clean(self):
        # get forms that actually have valid data
        count = 0
        for form in self.forms:
            try:
                if form.cleaned_data:
                    count += 1
            except AttributeError:
                # annoyingly, if a subform is invalid Django explicity raises
                # an AttributeError for cleaned_data
                pass
        if count < 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError('You must have at least one solution." \
                + " Please do not place solutions in the message field.')


class SolutionsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Solution
    extra = 0
    ordering = ('-updated', 'id')
    readonly_fields = ('solution_edited_by',)
    formset = SolutionsInlineFormset


class CardAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Card
    list_display = ('id', 'card_view_count', 'product', 'software', 'utility', 'function', 'markdown_safe_message', 'updated')
    ordering = ('-updated', 'software', 'product', 'utility', 'card_view_count', )
    list_filter = ('software', 'product')
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': CKEditorWidget},
    }

    inlines = [SolutionsInline, ]
    exclude = ['card_view_count', 'last_edited_by', 'card_created_by', ]
    readonly_fields = ('card_view_count', 'last_edited_by', 'card_created_by',)
    search_fields = ['id',
                     'message',
                     'tags',
                     'software__name',
                     'product__name',
                     'solution__cause',
                     'solution__cause_solution',
                     'error_code__code',
                     'function__name',
                     'utility__name',
                     'resolved__number',
                     'encountered__number',
                     ]
    save_as = True

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if change:
            obj.last_edited_by = request.user
        else:
            obj.card_created_by = request.user
        obj.save()

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        super(CardAdmin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for i in instances:
            if hasattr(i, 'solution_edited_by') and not i.solution_edited_by:
                i.solution_edited_by = request.user
            i.save()

        formset.save_m2m()
        super(CardAdmin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
```

Can't seem to figure out what is causing this error. And the only thing I changed recently was adding 'id' to the `list_display` and adding the `tags` field.

Tracked down the error line in /django/forms/models.py:

```py
class ModelMultipleChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    """A MultipleChoiceField whose choices are a model QuerySet."""
    widget = SelectMultiple
    hidden_widget = MultipleHiddenInput
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid_list': _('Enter a list of values.'),
        'invalid_choice': _('Select a valid choice. %(value)s is not one of the'
                            ' available choices.'),
        'invalid_pk_value': _('“%(pk)s” is not a valid value.')
    }
    def has_changed(self, initial, data):
        if self.disabled:
            return False
        if initial is None:
            initial = []
        if data is None:
            data = []
        if len(initial) != len(data):  # <-- Problem Child
            return True
        initial_set = {str(value) for value in self.prepare_value(initial)}
        data_set = {str(value) for value in data}
        return data_set != initial_set
```

Is there a way that I can debug this to see what variable or field is causing this?

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: add you complete error traceback in ***text*** format, not image of traceback

Comment: @ArakkalAbu will do.

Answer (score 0):

Your traceback says:

```
File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 449, in changed_data
    if field.has_changed(initial_value, data_value):
File "/home/corey/.virtualenvs/cardsite-_p-Jv6sl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 1385, in has_changed
    if len(initial) != len(data):
```

So you're trying to get len() of an integer (which you cannot do) in your forms.py

you can use `initial_string = str(intial)` to store a string that you can then use `len(initial_string)` to compare against, but I suspect there is a better way to do what you're trying to do. (what are you trying to do?)

Comment: I understand that. I just don't know what field or model it's trying to do that with. Django admin forms is a part of the django admin site, I haven't done any custom forms there. So I don't know where that `if len(initial) != len(data):` is coming from...

Comment: I'm just trying to create(add) a `Card` object using the Django Admin site. It was working fine, and then randomly started giving me this error. I even reverted to a commit before this started happening and I still get the error... Maybe it was a breaking change from Django...

Comment: I went into the source files for `django/forms/models.py`. Both `initial` and `data` are both lists, so they shouldn't have a problem with `len()`.

Comment: ah I see, I didn't notice it was a django form. hmmm

Comment: have you ran migrations?

Comment: yup, `makemigrations` and `migrate`. As well as `collectstatic`.

Comment: maybe there's an entry in your database from the one you tried adding before you reverted back, you could try inspecting and removing that if you find one

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being the `encountered` property on the `Card` class:

```py
encountered = models.ManyToManyField(Encountered, default=0, verbose_name='Encountered in', help_text='Version or Year. Select "N/A" if unknown.')
```

In the meantime I just changed it to a `ForeignKey`:

```py
encountered = models.ForeignKey(Encountered, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Encountered in', help_text='Version or Year. Select "N/A" if unknown.')
```